# How to send a mail such that when particular job executed in SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am creating a job such that executes the following SQL statement.

```
select * from emp where sal > 5000
```

It is scheduled to execute on 3 PM every day.

Now my question is:
How to configure mail or alert such that when the job executes I have to receive a mail or alert indiactes query executed suceesully

Answer (score 3):

You can add success and fail (or both) notifications for a job. You assign then to an operator who has email, pager etc contacts.

Example:

[How to: Notify an Operator of Job Status (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191130.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I would use the **SQL Server Agent** to send the emails.

You could so it by creating a stored procedure, and then run that in a job.
[Sending Automated Job Email Notifications in SQL Server with SMTP](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/sending-automated-job-email-notifications-in-sql-server-with-smtp/)

Also Microsoft's link on how to go about it in 2005.
[MSDN 2005 Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191130(SQL.90).aspx)

Here is another link on setting up SQL Server Mail in 2005, which you may find useful.
[Database Email](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/email_functionality_p1.aspx)